# CE Compliance: what is the limit of self-declaration for Industrial Control Panel?

Tags: emc, ce, compliance

We are a system integrator making custom electrical control cabinets. This is our first time on making panels for European customer, and of course they mandated the CE marking.

The control panel they need is just a bank of PLC and IOs, some breakers/relays/contactors, and a couple of inverters. All operates within 24VDC and 230VAC 1-phase/380VAC 3-phase.

Since our country doesn't really have any electrical codes for panel building, this is really new for us. I've looked at the CE Directives, and it looks like I'll need to comply with 3 directives: LVD, EMC, and Machinery Directives. After looking back and forth at them, I keep wondering one thing: What is the limit to which an industrial control panel can be marked CE Compliant with Declaration of Conformity, and when such industrial control panel must be assessed by notified body for Certificate of Conformity?

Also, for those with experience of making CE-compliant Industrial Control Panel, from the looks of it, I think we can comply with LVD and MD just fine, but the EMC directive is the most confusing one, like: do even every panel builder in EU has EM anechoic chamber just to do EMC testing or send every single made-to-order panel to EMC testing center to be tested? How can you even test such thing if you do not have access to the mechanical elements of the complete system or to run the complete system (e.g. retrofitting control panel for packaging machine. We only build the ICP, but the motors, servos, and mechanicals stay in customer site and not part of our responsibility in a project).

Sorry for my long question, since CE is just something 'alien' in our country and I can't even find proper local CE consultant here, most of them are CE testing centers and they wouldn't answer any of my question under the 'conflict of interest' terms.

Comment: I'm not 100% about this but, I think you need to issue a [declaration of incorporation](https://www.conformance.co.uk/ce-marking-assessment-specialists/129-declaration-of-incorporation)

Comment: @Andyaka that's on the MD side. From what I read, I can't use DoI on LVD and EMC.

Comment: That's because it's down to the final contractor in the chain to certify compliance.

Comment: @Andyaka so basically, we make the panel, compile all the tech documents, create DoI and hand over those to the ones responsible for the mechanical?

Comment: I believe that to be the case.

Comment: Whether the product is for general sale, or for a single fixed customer install is also important.  This article gives a bit more background https://incompliancemag.com/article/complying-with-the-eus-emc-directive-without-3rd-party-testing/

Comment: @colintd So the case is that our customer has an existing machine (made in the 70s, predates even EU existence). However, they need to upgrade the industrial control panel from relay-based to PLC system. No change will be done in the mechanics or motors by us (that's on customer), but we are asked to engineer and program a new ICP. My two cents is that it's single fixed and exempted from all directives, but that's where I have no clue.

Comment: @Jacobson123 The whole machine has to be CE marked and very likely inspected too. Is it used solely in restricted areas such as building sites or does it also move in traffic (tractor, wheel loader etc)?

Comment: I don't think you are exempted from EMC (in particular because your kit could in theory interfere with neighbours of your customer, which wouldn't be acceptable), but you can take the "standards route", and simply certify that what you are providing has been well designed and manufactured in line with standard practice, and if tested should meet the relevant emissions standards.  You remain on the hook if there are problems, but in the case you describe this is unlikely.  It is much more of an issue with mass market products, because the cost of recall on failure could be massive.

Comment: As noted by other commenters, I would be more worried about the safety related elements of the overall machine, in particular if you are reworking the safety loop circuits.

Comment: @Lundin nope. It's a static machine (inline packaging machine) in a building, not a mobile equipment.

Comment: @colintd TBH, I don't even understand why they need this. The machine itself isn't in EU, but just because it's an EU company, suddenly they want every machinery of theirs be CE-marked, even on their plants outside EU. I doubt they even check for any non-compliance, but maybe because of the insurance thingy?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose this applies:

- None of the products integrated in the cabinet are your own.
- All of the more complex products such as PSU, PLC or IO modules are CE marked.
- You didn't do anything major that will impact EMC, such as the bad idea of routing sensitive signals close together with the VAC supply cables etc.

Then you should be able to reason about EMC compliance in documentation and perform a self declaration against the EMC directive.

Please note however that the EMC directive also covers ESD during both mounting and use of the panel and here your design *will* directly impact ESD. ESD testing is one of the cheaper parts of EMC testing though, so maybe consider at least doing that at a test house - you'll want to be able to confidently claim the toughest ESD class of EN 61000-4-2, "level 4" 8kV contact/15kV air, as is custom for high integrity industrial systems.

As noted in comments, the main responsibility of EMC compliance otherwise falls on the company putting the end product on the market. But naturally they will not be too happy with you if your product is what caused them to fail an expensive EMC test.

So you need to make a design suitable for connecting nasty things like motors and servos. For example if your panel misbehaves because of voltage surges or reverse EMF caused by a motor, then you can't come claiming that you didn't know that such phenomenons existed because then your panel is *not* suitable for the intended purpose and very likely not compliant to the EMC directive.

I actually don't think EMC is your main concern here, but LVD including electrical safety, safety grounds and so on. Here you should probably involve a test house for LVD compliance, since a formal test report from a neutral party will be invaluable in case of accidents, insurance claims and similar.

> and I can't even find proper local CE consultant here, most of them are CE testing centers and they wouldn't answer any of my question under the 'conflict of interest' terms.

Wow, that sounds like a great country then. Because in the EU, the test houses have no such qualms but happily first take your money to act as consultant and then take your money to perform testing as well. So if you paid them a lot of money for consulting, the test will surely pass... now, was it it because they gave great technical advise or because of the cash you already poured at them, or both...?

Anyway, just contact some test house in Europe directly? TÜV, Intertek, BSI, STEEP etc. Ideally one present in the country you seek to export to.

Comment: I did contact TÜV (both Sud and Nord) and BSI local branch here in my country. None of them want to answer any question about this. They said that they are only testing centers, and all they will do is give us quote and test based on the list of standards we send to them for testing. I even asked them how to consult and they just said 'no, we don't do consulting, nor we are able to due to conflict of interest' and just that. Either they don't have anyone that understand CE in my local branches or else, IDK. Maybe I need to call their head office then.

Comment: @Jacobson123 Well, feel free to poke me with questions directly in the chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering. I have lots of experience of very similar products since I work with control systems for heavy machinery.